# Strange behavior of racket GUI `timer%`

Tags: user-interface, racket

I was trying to writing a simple program, which shows the current time and updates each second. However, when I run the code below

```
#lang racket/gui

(require racket/date)

(define frame (new frame%
                   [label "Not Functioning Timer"]
                   [width 300]
                   [height 100]))

(new timer%
     [interval 1000]
     [notify-callback (lambda ()
                        ;(display (format "The time is: ~a"
                        ;                 (date->string (current-date) #t)))
                        ;(newline) ; the commented lines work
                        ;; however the behavior of the following lines is weird
                        (send time-msg
                              set-label
                              (format "The time is: ~a"
                                      (date->string (current-date) #t))))])


(define time-msg (new message%
                      [parent frame]
                      [label "nothing so far..."]))

(send frame show #t)
```

I got

[image: program snapshot]

where the description involving current time is missing. However, when I uncomment the `(display ...)` lines, it yields the output:

```
(object:timer% ...)
The time is: Monday, March 26th, 2018 12:14:33am
The time is: Monday, March 26th, 2018 12:14:34am
The time is: Monday, March 26th, 2018 12:14:35am
The time is: Monday, March 26th, 2018 12:14:36am
...
```

which functions well.

I don't understand why it happens. Please help!

By the way, what should I do to align the text to the left side instead of placing them in the center?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the components are sized when the container is first rendered. Then your message for the time is too long.

```
(define time-msg (new message%
                      [parent frame]
                      [auto-resize #t]
                      [label "nothing so far..."]))
```

If you add set the `auto-resize` property to `#t` you should see what you desire.